# What's difference between the original and modified code?

Tags: c, structure

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char name[128];
    int salary;
} Employee;


Employee *input_employee()
{
    Employee *e = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    scanf("%[^/]s" , e.name);
    return e;
}
```

which is called in `main()` and gives a compilation error, however, after a minor changed in `input_employee()` function, namely:

`e.name;` changed to `e->name;`

It compiled without errors.

What is the meaning of the correction and what was the initial error?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Structure is not a scalar type.

Comment: ... Also you do not need the cast for `malloc`  in C. It is not good practice

Comment: `e->name` is short for `(*e).name`. If `e` is of type `Empolyee`, you use `e.name`. If `e` is of type `Employee*`, you use `e->name` or `(*e).name` (because `*e` is of type `Employee`).

Comment: @2501 since when structure became a variable? I knew it as data type.:)

Comment: This should be explained in any C textbook or tutorial, in the chapter on structures and pointers. Go back to the books.

Comment: @SouravGhosh  Variable e is a structure or a pointer to a structure, depending on how it is defined. Whether one is referring to a structure type or a variable that has a structure type, that type or that object's type is not a scalar type. Your first comment is misleading.

Comment: @2501 Yes, you're right, my interpretation was wrong. Will be more careful next time. Thanks for correcting me. :)

Comment: @2501 So, to correct the above statement, can we say "arithmetic and pointer type" to spot out the differences? But that would exclude a non-pointer structure type, as they are aggregate, so what's the best way to go there?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Where did you get arithmetic types? `Employee *e` is a pointer, and `Employee e` is an aggregate, that's it.

Comment: @2501 I removed that comment. I was asking in general, to point out the differences between a pointer(referenced) and non-pointer type. How do we say it?

Answer (score 1):

To access a stuct member in an object instance you use the *dot (access) operator* `.`, however when the instance of the object is a pointer you need to dereference it first and then access the members, namely: `(*e).name` which is equivalent to `e->name`, called the *arrow operator*